# Problem with result of View plugin

Tags: views

I have this View plugin for displaying which panelized node have which layout:

```
class unionen_custom_panelizer_handler_panelizer_layout extends views_handler_field_entity {
  function render($values) {
    if ($entity = $this->get_value($values)) {
      if (isset($entity->panelizer->display->layout)) {
        $layout = $entity->panelizer->display->layout;
      }
      else {
        $layout = t('No layout found');
      }
      return $layout;
    }
  }
}
```

The result is correct when displayed in a pane, page or other display, but when I preview it, displays the wrong results - panel layouts that are not used at all for the panelized nodes. It is not a biggie, I just want to understand why I get the wrong results....